# How to use regex to get value from response header in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am using regex to get value from response header in JMeter,
I try to get the last value in query `tt_unixtime` and I failed.

Can someone please advise how to user regex to get the last value?

I Created a variable called `time44444444` and I want it to get the value from the response,
the problem is that it stored nothing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share your code. And explain in more details.

Comment: From Review: Please do not post text in images. Please edit your question and fix those issues.

Comment: The first PIC is the header response, In the middle PIC is what I do in Jmeter, and the last PIC is the results that is nothing.  I want to get the value of tt_unixtime.    I need to store it in a variable, so I Tried the command tt_unixtime=(.*?)    but it did not get the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues in your [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) settings for getting the value matched:

Apply To:  `Response Headers`

Regular expression should be `(\w+)` - any alphanumeric characters

Template should be `$1$` - first group

Match No. should be be `1` - find first match

> The template used to create a string from the matches found. This is an arbitrary string with special elements to refer to groups within the regular expression. The syntax to refer to a group is: '$1$' to refer to group 1

Comment: Hey user7294900 I put (\w+) in the regex expression and still not any results, can you please be more specific, what to mention in this regex to get the value? the number after tt_time regards