# Jmeter unable to replace the dynamic values captured in web header based on a regular expression using Jmeter Corelation Extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am trying to use Jmeter corelation Extractor plugin, and able to extract the dynamic values based on the boundaries that have specified. However, I am unable to replace one of the values in one of the header of the request/s. In Jmeter corelation extractor, the values are replaced based on the regular expression I specify to identify "where" to replace.

```
The header name is : X-XSRF-TOKEN
I tried specifying regular expressions as:
X-XSRF-TOKEN=(.+)
X-XSRF-TOKEN:(.+)
X-XSRF-TOKEN (.+)
```

The captured value is not replaced in any of the above 3 attempts.

I see it as below, in the original request :

```
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-XSRF-TOKEN: zajGpU76-I5-0N1WGmKjXX4PX1snVyXx4A
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use regex to get value from response header in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708674/how-to-use-regex-to-get-value-from-response-header-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your 2nd regular expression is correct however it might be a good idea to allow optional [whitespaces](https://regexone.com/lesson/whitespaces) like:

   ```
   X-XSRF-TOKEN:\s*(.+)
   ```
2. Make sure to apply the correlation rule to `RESPONSE_HEADERS` as it looks like you're trying to extract the value from the [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) and by default Correlation Extractor is looking into response body.

   [image]
3. If you're getting this `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header with **each** response it might be a better idea to go for a single Regular Expression Extractor placed at the same level as HTTP Request samplers (it will be applied to all of them according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide))

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, addition of \s* did the trick.