# How to get https value from response headers in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have to get the sid value from response header and use this value in next request. but my regular expression is not picking up the value
Response:
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Location: https://abc.be.com/tsg/de.aspx?sid=s44mNTM3MkRCRUMtRkEfrgtfTEwRDMyQUZFJDI1MDYxMTE5m12s
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Date: Mon, 07 Jun 2021 10:16:04 GMT
Content-Length: 0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqclb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm6Dj.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use regex to get value from response header in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708674/how-to-use-regex-to-get-value-from-response-header-in-jmeter)

Comment: Please post the regex

Answer (score 0):

I have tried my option and found solution my using the following regex:

Location: .+/de.aspx?sid=(.*?)\n

Comment: you can refer following blog to find out more how to extract values : https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-tokens-and-session-ids-to-variables

Answer (score 0):

Just `sid=(.*)` should do the trick for you:

[image]

Where:

- `()` - grouping
- `.`  - matches any character
- `*` - zero or more occurrences

So it will start from `sid=` and capture everything till the line break

More information:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)